# PostgreSQL AFTER INSERT trigger prevents insert

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have a PostgreSQL 9.3 database. I use a log4net configuration to insert the errors in a table: log_messages.
I have a webpage that shows the errors in a nice way with charts and such.
Because I use a rather complex view this webpage is very slow, so I moved to a materialized view. My page is fast again.

Now I need to keep my materialized view in sync with my table/view. So I created a AFTER INSERT trigger on the table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER refresh_mv_insert
  AFTER INSERT
  ON log_messages
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE refresh_mv();
```

My refresh_mv() is more complicated but even this simplified version doesn't work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION refresh_mv()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
 l_view_name character varying := 'mv_log_messages';
begin

  EXECUTE 'REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW ' || l_view_name;  

  RETURN NEW;
end;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

When I change it to an anonymous procedure the full and simplified version do work. So it seems I have an error in the Trigger part.

I've been reading documentation and similar Q&A for two days now but I can't get it to work.
Any help is much appreciated.

**Edit**: Clarification

In my full trigger procedure I use a config table to store the refresh timestamp and I don't refresh within an hour.

When I enable the trigger the record is not saved into the log_messages table.

I don't know how to read any trigger errors. Where can I find them?

Here's my full code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION refresh_mv()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
 l_last_refresh timestamp;
 l_view_name character varying := 'mv_log_messages';
 l_num_new smallint;
 l_refresh boolean := false;
begin
  l_refresh := false;
  -- check the last time:
  select last_refresh, num_new into l_last_refresh, l_num_new from config where view_name = l_view_name;

  -- refresh every hour
  if (l_last_refresh  + interval '1 hour' < current_timestamp) then
    l_refresh := true;
  end if;

  -- refresh every 10 inserts, but not more often than every 10 minutes:
  if (l_num_new > 9 and l_last_refresh  + interval '10 minutes' < current_timestamp) then
    l_refresh := true;
  end if;

  if l_refresh then
    -- Reset config and do refresh:
    update config set last_refresh = current_timestamp, num_new = 0 where view_name = l_view_name;
    -- this line prevents the insertion of the record EXECUTE 'REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW ' || l_view_name;  
  else
    -- Update counter:
    update config set num_new = l_num_new + 1 where view_name = l_view_name;
  end if;

  RETURN NULL;
end;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

This trigger works because I commented the line `EXECUTE 'REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW ' || l_view_name;`

Comment: What error are you getting? Can you elaborate a bit on how this does not work?

Comment: Unrelated, but: you should make that a statement level trigger. Otherwise you would refresh the MVIEW hundred times if an INSERT inserted a 100 rows.

Comment: Also you should return `NULL` in an `AFTER` trigger.

Comment: I updated my post.

Comment: I'm still struggling with this. Everything in my trigger is working except the `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW ` call. Is there another way to update my MV automatically?